# Why is UIScrollView not working in xcode 7?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout, ios9.3

I created a UIScrollView and SubView in XCode 5 and iOS 7. Its Working fine but I am running in XCode 7 and its not scrolling. I set AutoLayouts to UIScrollview. I wrote code in ViewDidLayoutSubviews Method.

> billViewScrolled2  is CustomView (UIView)

```
-(void)viewdidload{

[super viewdidload];
    self.scrollViewTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
    self.billViewScrolled2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}

    -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
        [self.scrollViewTwo setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.billViewScrolled2.frame.size.width, 21 * [billDataArray count])];
        if (self.billViewScrolled2) {
            UIEdgeInsets scrollViewInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

            scrollViewInsets.bottom = (CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollViewTwo.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(self.billViewScrolled2.bounds)) / [billDataArray count]+ 160;

            self.scrollViewTwo.contentInset = scrollViewInsets;
        } else if (self.billViewScrolled2)
            self.scrollViewTwo.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) + 1.0f);
    }
```

Please help me.